# How to make order in group_by records query in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is my current code

```
cat = Category.select(:id, :name, :parent, :jobs_count).group_by{|p| p.parent}

cat.each do |parent, childs|
   = parent
   childs.each do |name|
     = name.name
   end
end
```

the results of this are,

**Technology** (The parent)

- Ruby
- Rails
- Programming

Now I want to order `childs` records by `jobs_count`, I am trying to do it using the code below,

```
childs.order(jobs_count: :desc).each do |name|
Error:
=> undefined method `order' for #<Array:0x007f11cc08a2c0>
```

also like that into main query

```
Category.select(:id, :name, :parent, :jobs_count).group_by{|p| p.parent}.order(jobs_count: :desc)
Error:
#=> undefined method `order' for #<Array:0x007f11cc242e50>
```

It not working for me, how can I order the records by `jobs_count`

Comment: when you say it doesn't work, do you get an error message in the query, do you get data in the wrong order?

Comment: For the both cases it's showing `undefined method order for #<Array:0x007f11cc242e50>`

Comment: can you specify the version of ruby, rails that you are using

Comment: I think the issue has solved by answer, thanks

Comment: parent and jobs_count is fields of category table . right ?

Comment: Yes! that is @Vishal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can be using `sort_by` method like on the `childs.each` block like the following

```
childs.sort_by{|j| - j.jobs_count }.each do |name|
```

So the full code is:

```
cat.each do |parent, childs|
   = parent
   childs.sort_by{|j| - j.jobs_count }.each do |name|
     = name.name
   end
end
```

It should work.

Comment: It's always better to do the sorting in database if you can, its much faster than doing it in ruby